# Visual Studio 2017 Python can't debug files

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Python. When I want to run my file, I have to do Project > 'Start with Debugging' or Project > 'Start without Debugging' and there are no shortcuts for these, so it's very inconvenient
to run my files. It is fine to set projects as 'StartUp project' and then run with F5 (Debug > Start Debugging) but can't I do it with just my files (File > New > File..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017, we could start debug a Python project with shortcuts of F5 (Start with Debugging) and Ctrl + F5 (Start without Debugging). It is debugging for project.

The debugging for a Python file doesn't have shortcuts by default. You need to right-click the file and choose Start with Debugging or Start without Debugging.

If you just want to debug one of the Python files, you could set the file as Startup file through right-click the file -> choose Set as Startup file. Then you can debug this file through F5 or Ctrl + F5 until you set another file as startup file.

Comment: I didn't know that we can set the files as startup files, thank you very much.